# MySQL foreign key reference

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient
(
    inId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    inName VARCHAR(30),
    inSupplier VARCHAR(30),
    inPrice double,
    inStock INT,
    imageFile VARCHAR(100)
);
create table baguette(
    inId int not null primary key,
    inName VARCHAR(30),
    inAmount double,
    FOREIGN KEY (inId) REFERENCES ingredient(inId),
    FOREIGN KEY (inName) REFERENCES ingredient(inName)
);
```

When I tried to create table baguette, the error below was printed.

Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. 
Missing index for constraint 'baguette_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'ingredient' 0.000 sec

Doesn't inName and inName have the same type?
What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, they have the same type, but inName must be a unique key in your table ingredient, that´s what the error says _Missing index for constraint 'baguette_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'ingredient'_

Comment: Just remove the second foreign key (inName) command and it will be fine. You don't even need the inName column in baguette - it's redundant.

Comment: thank you for your comments.. but i need inName in baguette

Comment: Note that money is rarely DOUBLE; it's why DECIMAL was invented.

Comment: `but i need inName in baguette` if that's true then you probably shouldn't be using an RDBMS